# Help with Linear Mixed Model creation and correct post-hoc in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I have a table with 10 columns;

1. Day
2. Subject
3. Treatment_1 - Treatment_8

I wanted to run a 2 factor repeated measures ANOVA but I have quite a few missing values so from what I read a LMM is the best option.
My initial model is:

`results = lmer(Treatment_1 - Treatment_8 ~ Day + (1|Subject))`

And I have been getting post-hoc analysis with :

`summary(glht(results, linfct=mcp(Day ="Tukey")), test = adjusted("none"))`

I was initially using bonferroni but it seemed too strict because I was getting too many type 2 errors.

Is my model  and Post-Hoc correct? Also how would I cite the Post-Hoc in a paper, is it Tukey's multiple comparisons? Also if I use bonferroni instead, is that after Tukey's or does it take the place of Tukeys?

Comment: I don’t see how you could know if you were making type II errors unless the data are simulated from a known configuration.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but after Day 2 most treatments become significant and stay that way through the rest of the experiment, sometimes the treatments become not significant on a day where there has in reality been no change but because of missing values seems to have high variance that only becomes apparent from bonferroni correction but not the others.

Comment: Well, you really can’t know. There’s hardly anything *less* strict than the Bonferroni method; it’s pretty conservative.

Comment: Less strict = conservative? I was under the assumption that Bonferroni was the most conservative correction, ie: only most likely values would be returned as significant?

Comment: Bonferroni *is* about the most conservative adjustment. I guess I just misinterpreted what you meant by "strict."